# What are manifest files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I'm looking at the property pages for a typical C++ project.

But I'm unfamiliar with the "Manifest File" section, inside the linker section.

What are they? What do they do? Do I need them?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Generate Manifest**
[/MANIFEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifest-create-side-by-side-assembly-manifest?view=msvc-160) specifies that the linker should create a side-by-side manifest file.

**Manifest File**
[/MANIFESTFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestdependency-specify-manifest-dependencies?view=msvc-160) lets you change the default name of the manifest file. The default name of the manifest file is the file name with .manifest appended.

**Additional Manifest Dependencies**
[/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestdependency-specify-manifest-dependencies?view=msvc-160) lets you specify attributes that will be placed in the dependency section of the manifest file.

**Allow Isolation**
Specifies behavior for manifest lookup. ([/ALLOWISOLATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/allowisolation-manifest-lookup?view=msvc-160):NO)

**Enable User Account Control (UAC)**
Specifies whether or not User Account Control is enabled. ([/MANIFESTUAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest?view=msvc-160), /MANIFESTUAC:NO)

**UAC Execution Level**
Specifies the requested execution level for the application when running with User Account Control. (/MANIFESTUAC:level=[value])

Choices

`asInvoker` - UAC Execution Level: as invoker.

`highestAvailable` - UAC Execution Level: highest available.

`requireAdministrator` - UAC Execution Level: require administrator.

**UAC Bypass UI Protection**
Specifies whether or not to bypass user interface protection levels for other windows on the desktop. Set this property to 'Yes' only for accessibility applications. ([/MANIFESTUAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest?view=msvc-160):uiAccess=[true | false])

Comment: Apologies this description really isn't that much more helpful than the official docs. Do you think you could clarify the intent of manifest files in a more clear cut way? Why should I as a developer care about these linker options?

Comment: @jpr33 About what is the Manifests, I suggest you could refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/manifests)